# Extract rows from data frame based on multiple identifiers in another data frame

Tags: r

I would like to extract a selection of rows from a data frame based on multiple identifying variables contained in another data frame. Consider the following illustrative data set:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5), ref=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","F","G","H"), amount=c(10,15,20,25,30,35,-35,40,45))
required <- data.frame(id=c(2,3,4,4), ref=c("B","D","E","F"))
```

I would like the output in a data frame with id, ref and amount as follows:

id  ref amount
2   B   15
3   D   25
4   E   30
4   F   35
4   F   -35

Note in particular that id 4 and ref F have two matches from the df with amounts 35 and -35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to merge:

```
merge(df, required)
##    id ref amount
##  1  2   B     15
##  2  3   D     25
##  3  4   E     30
##  4  4   F     35
##  5  4   F    -35
```